# Join traversal object results in ArangoDB

Tags: join, arangodb, aql

I am using ArangoDB's [traversal object](https://docs.arangodb.com/Traversals/UsingTraversalObjects.html) in order to traverse a recursive group membership structure while avoiding following cycles.  There are cases where I need to join the results of two separate traversals.  Is there an efficient way to leverage [AQL](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/GraphTraversals.html) to join the traversal results?  I'm currently joining the results in memory with javascript.

Comment: Did the answer work for you? if yes, can you mark it 'accepted'? If not, whats missing?

Comment: @dothebart Thanks for your answer.  I haven't had a chance to look at this problem recently because our team's priorities shifted but I've tried something similar to your suggestion in the past, and it indeed gave the correct result but it had poor performance.  Additionally my particular problem has many cycles, and repeatedly visiting the same node has resulted in further poor performance.  So in addition to finding the intersection between multiple sets of visited vertices, where the depth of each tree could be around 5 or so,  the query needs to specify a way to avoid cycles.

Comment: I've used the GRAPH_NEIGHBORS function to get vertices from a node to avoid cycles, but either making multiple calls to this or intersecting multiple results of its calls resulted in poor performance.

Comment: Please note that the GRAPH_*  functions are deprecated with ArangoDB 3.0; [see our migration guide how to upgrade](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/cookbook/AQL/MigratingGraphFunctionsTo3.html). In general, you should share your solution in a separate article, so others can also refer to it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to explain this using [the traversal graph](https://docs.arangodb.com/Graphs/index.html#the-traversal-graph). We do two traversals in `ANY` direction, so the number of results is a little bigger. We start it at points that have neighbors in common which will become the result of the join operation. One query will look at `A` and `E` which should have `B` in common, but others of the iteration not.

The basic iteration:

```
FOR v IN 1..1 ANY 'circles/A' GRAPH 'traversalGraph' RETURN v._key
```

Starting from `circles/A` this results in `["B","G"]`, starting from `circles/E` this results in `["F", "B"]` - so its obvious, we should only get `"B"` as the result of the join.

Our first possible approach is to use two sub queries and join them using [`INTERSECTION`](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Functions/Array.html):

```
LET firstTraversal = (FOR v IN 1..1 ANY 'circles/A' GRAPH 'traversalGraph' RETURN v)
LET secondTraversal = (FOR v IN 1..1 ANY 'circles/E' GRAPH 'traversalGraph' RETURN v)
RETURN INTERSECTION(firstTraversal, secondTraversal)
```

A possible problem here could be, that a full depth comparison of the objects will be done, which may become expensive. Another approach therefore could be to join them using their `_key` attribute:

```
LET firstTraversal = (FOR v IN 1..1 ANY 'circles/A' GRAPH 'traversalGraph' RETURN v)
LET secondTraversal = (FOR v IN 1..1 ANY 'circles/E' GRAPH 'traversalGraph' RETURN v)
FOR oneSet IN firstTraversal
  FOR otherSet IN secondTraversal
    FILTER oneSet._key == otherSet._key RETURN oneSet
```